# socks5 proxy + proxifier doesn't work for some connections

Tags: vpn, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy, socks, socks5

I live in a country where many foreign websites are blocked. I have been using a socks5 proxy by SSH dynamic port forwarding and Proxifier to circumvent this restriction. Recently, I found that some connections in a game that involve multiplayer contents are blocked, even though Proxifier is set to send all connections through the proxy. I can still browse webpages like google using the socks5 proxy, which means that the proxy is working normally. I'm now using Panda VPN's global VPN mode, and it works. Is there a way to make socks5 proxy + Proxifier work as well? I tried the "handle direct connections" options in Proxifier, and it doesn't help. I prefer using the socks5 proxy instead of VPN. It would be great if I can solve the current problem using the socks5 proxy only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't delete questions and repost them again under a new user!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is just a repost of a recently added and deleted question.

Comment: Sorry, which question are you referring to? This is the first time I post here. I previously posted the same question in Network Engineering, but the moderator said this question should be asked here, so I post the question here instead.

Comment: @Terry there was a question with the same topic created and deleted a few days ago, please excuse my comment if your question is different. I raised a flag, so a moderator can decide. Other then that please rephrase your question, a "wall of text" is not very reader friendly.

Comment: @Terry since it was deleted I can not show you which question I'm referring to.